# Older SDK disappeared after installing new Xcode version

Tags: iphone, xcode

Why are old SDKs beeing removed when installing a new version of xcode with new Iphone SDK ?
Now we have v4, what settings do I have to make in order that the apps still work with 3.x ?

Thanks

Comment: Seems the "how to fix" is sorted. The "why" is more complicated than we thought during the beta, confer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the Base SDK to 4.0 and Deployment Target to 3.x. Or, in modern conditions, the Base SDK to Latest and Deployment Target to whatever you need.

Answer (score 7):

Although 'Zoul' has most succinctly answered the question, I shall make an attempt to elaborate on the 2 settings and point to some useful documents which will help others who are new to the situation.

1. Base SDK Version: This indicates the version of the SDK based on which the program has been compiled. This can be set from the "Build Settings" for the project or target. You can use API code from Apple in your code introduced up-to that version and compiler will know all the symbols and compile without any issues.
2. Deployment target: This is a declaration from your side about the minimum iOS version which should be installed on the user's device to run your code. This setting can be found under "Info" section for Project and "Summary" section for a particular target. Now, important thing to understand is that your code will not automatically run smoothly on devices with older versions of the iOS if you are using API code introduced in later version by Apple. These can be new classes/methods/frameworks introduced by Apple in later version. You have to ensure by writing necessary conditional code and provide alternate code path to gracefully degrade for older iOS version which does not have the newer API. It is up-to you to handle version incompatibilities.

Apple documentation on the subject can be found in "[SDK Compatibility Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163-BCICHGIE)".

To know about the changes with different versions of iOS refer "[What's new in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008244-SW1)".

This topic is also discussed in "[iOS Development Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/120-Building_and_Running_Applications/building_and_running_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH6-SW2)" under section "Building and Running Application". Refer sub-section "Specifying the Runtime Environment".

Answer (score 3):

If you have backups of your system from something like Time Machine (and you better!) you can copy the older SDKs from the backup located at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs - then just restart XCode and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

If you still have the problem after you set Deployment target at least as low as your desired SDK, then you need to download that SDK. Luckily, Xcode helps us here also:

- look after Simulator selector in top left of your Xcode and select More Simulators. It will open a page like the one below:

[image: Download SDK view]

- just select the SDK you need to test your app against.

Answer (score 1):

3.2.3 last beta did remove all other SDK's cause to many people tried publish Apps developed with the beta SDK, which will not be accepted. I guess GM is doing still the same

If you want to develop for 4.0,3.2 and 3.0 (plus 3.0,3.1,3.1.2,3.1.3)
do the following

- sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all (This will uninstall the current XCode installation)
- Then install first old XCode (3.2 final) in default folder (/Developer)
- Then install the new XCode (3.2.3 GM) in other folder (/DeveloperBeta)
- This way you will have both. And can launch xcode from either /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app or /DeveloperBeta/Applications/Xcode.app

Comment: This is not necessary.  You can develop for all versions of the OS with the Base SDK set to 4.0 and the Deployment Target set to those other versions.

Comment: You're right, just as zoul said. But do you get all the warnings/errors  if you use f.e. MPMoviePlayerViewController which is not available in SDKs below 3.2 with SDK set to 4.0 and different deployment target ? I prefer having those instead of looking up the availability and stuff.